# Mask credit card input on blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input, mask

I have an input in my form that takes a credit card number.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CCnumber" ng-model="CCnumber" ng-blur="balanceParent.maskCreditCard(this)">
```

On blur, I'd like to mask the credit card input like so:

4444************

And then on focus, I'd like to return the original credit card number:

4444333322221111

Using ng-blur, I'm able to do simple javascript to return a masked input.

```
    vm.maskCreditCard = function(modalScope) {
      if(modalScope.CCnumber){
      var CCnumber = modalScope.CCnumber.replace(/\s+/g, '');
      var parts = CCnumber.match(/[\s\S]{1,4}/g) || [];
      for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if(i !== 0) {
        parts[i] = '****';
      }
    }
    modalScope.CCnumber = parts.join("");
  }
};
```

My problem is getting that number back once the user focuses on the input once more. Is there a way to preserve the inital value of the input while also masking it?

Comment: sure, just add a new variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create an attribute directive for this. Angular best practice is to manipulate the DOM inside a directive instead of a controller.

In your case, when you bind the `blur` event to the element, you should save the current value into a variable. You can then access this variable when you bind the `focus` event.

```
 angular.module('CreditApp', [])
     .directive('maskInput', function() {
         return {
             restrict: "A",
             link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                 elem.bind("blur", function() {
                     var number = elem.val();
                     elem.val(elem.val().slice(0,4) + elem.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, '*'));
                 });
                 elem.bind("focus", function() {
                     elem.val(number);
                });
             }
        }
  });
```

I just created a plunkr for this

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZywTmF7xfz2FyvRULLjL?p=preview

Try typing a credit card number in the input box and click outside the box. This is the `blur` event and the credit card number will be masked. Now, click inside the box again, and the value will be restored.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! Will this preserve the ng-model value as well?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `data-` attributes to keep it hold. I know a jQuery version:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#cCard").blur(function () {
    cCardNum = $(this).val();
    $(this).data("value", cCardNum);
    if (cCardNum.length > 4) {
      $(this).val(cCardNum.substr(0, 4) + "*".repeat(cCardNum.length - 4))
    }
  }).focus(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="cCard" />
```

This is a polyfill for the `String.prototype.repeat` function:

```
if (!String.prototype.repeat) {
  String.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    'use strict';
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError('can\'t convert ' + this + ' to object');
    }
    var str = '' + this;
    count = +count;
    if (count != count) {
      count = 0;
    }
    if (count < 0) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be non-negative');
    }
    if (count == Infinity) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must be less than infinity');
    }
    count = Math.floor(count);
    if (str.length == 0 || count == 0) {
      return '';
    }
    // Ensuring count is a 31-bit integer allows us to heavily optimize the
    // main part. But anyway, most current (August 2014) browsers can't handle
    // strings 1 << 28 chars or longer, so:
    if (str.length * count >= 1 << 28) {
      throw new RangeError('repeat count must not overflow maximum string size');
    }
    var rpt = '';
    for (;;) {
      if ((count & 1) == 1) {
        rpt += str;
      }
      count >>>= 1;
      if (count == 0) {
        break;
      }
      str += str;
    }
    return rpt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find working Plunker for angularjs directive to format Card Number in **xxxxxxxxxxxx3456** Fromat.[Plunker for Card Number Masking](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9oYZkqClSqe3plzDH44?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

   .directive('maskInput', function() {
    return {
            require: "ngModel",
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
             },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var orig = scope.ngModel;
                var edited = orig;
                scope.ngModel = edited.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + edited.slice(-4);

                elem.bind("blur", function() {
                    var temp;
                    orig  = elem.val();
                    temp = elem.val();
                    elem.val(temp.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + temp.slice(-4));
                });

                elem.bind("focus", function() {
                    elem.val(orig);
               });  
            }
       };
   })
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.creditCardNumber = "1234567890123456";
  }]);
```